# Using Raspberry pi as a wifi hotspot and sharing a SOCKS proxy through it

Tags: raspbian, hotspot

hi ive been trying to figure this out for a few days but i lack the technical know how to properly implement this i am attempt to do this guide on my raspberry pi running rasbian
https://np.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/41cx00/sideload_a_tethering_app_for_your_iphone/

i have already created a hotspot with RaspAP and done all the necessary changes to the ipv4 section and it all works fine on a different device to browse the web as long as the browser has an addon to use SOCKS proxy

my issue is in the step 4

**Last, go to the Proxies tab
Select SOCKS proxy
In the SOCKS Proxy Server field enter the address and port that appear on your iPhone screen
Press OK
Press Apply (It is important that you ht apply or nothing you did will start working yet)**

in which i can add the socks proxy to the AP itself so i can use it on devices which can not be configured to use SOCKS proxy such as an ipad or PS4

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you!

edit: additional information
my socks proxy is 10.3.41.86:3128 and i am accessing the raspberry pi hotspot from 10.3.41.1

Comment: Please paste the shortest block of code that reproduces the problem. (We’ll format it!). It's great that you're falling a tutorial, but many here won't click and read through it to understand the problem, so make it easier for them. If you have any other doubts about how to write your question, take a look at our [site's tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: thank you for replying there is no code im trying to follow steps but im not sure how to do it in rasbian as there is not network adapter gui

STEP 4

    Next the subnet mask will be 255.255.255.0
    For router put in the address that is in the tethering app.
    Go to the DNS Tab and click "+" in the bottom left and enter the address
    Last, go to the Proxies tab
    Select SOCKS proxy
    In the SOCKS Proxy Server field enter the address and port

i need a way to connect the pi to a SOCKS5 proxy that is hosted from my phone but i do not know how